# Finding artifacts using bulk_extractor in different methods

Tags: forensics, bulk-extractor

I have specific number of artifact, and I want to search for those particular artifacts in the disk image using the `bulk_extractor` tool via different methods using Random Sampling, Stop List, Alert List, or Search Text. I want to know which method is most efficient, and how can I reproduce such test scenario and get results.

Comment: Are you dealing with an incredibly huge disk image that you need to sample? If not, just run against the entire image.

Comment: Hi, No I am learning on the tool. Trying to figure out whats best way of doing this. I want to search for artifacts with those 4 methods,  which one will yield faster result to me. And If you can tell him how to run, I can record times by myself, but right now bulk extractor doesn't seem to do random sampling or alert list or blacklist or search regex on artifact..

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes each of the methods that you list. They are different and not commensurable.

### Random Sampling

This approach picks a set of random sectors, sorts them, and analyzes them in order. (They are sorted because it's faster to seek randomly chosen sectors in sort order than in random order if you have a mechanical drive.) This is useful for analyzing 1TB of data in 10 minutes, as discussed by [Simson Garfinkel in this 2012 video presentation.](https://crcs.seas.harvard.edu/event/simson-l-garfinkel-digital-forensics-innovation-searching-terabyte-data-10-minutes)

### Stop List

A stop list is a list of [words that should be ignored.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) For example, there are many email addresses in the Linux kernel: you should probably ignore them. However, you probably want to use a context-aware stop list (which bulk_extractor supports) so that you only ignore the Linux developer's email addresses when they appear in the Kernel, and not when they appear elsewhere (such as in an email message).

### Altert List

Sometimes you are working on a case and you want to know immediate if you target's email address is found. You can add that target's email address to the alert list, and you will be alerted.

### Search Text

This is text that you might be search for.

Your question asks: "which method is most efficient." This question doesn't make sense, because the methods implement different functionality and you didn't define what you mean by "efficient."

Your second question asks: "How can I reproduce such test scenario and get results." It is not clear what this question means.